# Magento 2 - How to remove options from mass action in sales order page in admin?

Tags: magento2, order-grid, massaction

I want to remove **Print Invoices** and **Print Shipping Labels** from mass action select menu available on order view page.

[image]

I tried adding

```
<action name="pdfinvoices_order">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</action>
```

in **/app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `actionDisable` node like as below.

`Your_Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="cancel">
                <settings>
                    <url path="sales/order/massCancel"/>
                    <type>cancel</type>
                    <label translate="true">Cancel</label>
                    <actionDisable>true</actionDisable>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Make sure `Your_Module` is loaded before `Magento_Sales`.

Comment: This is the best answer and doesn't require replacing the whole uicomponent like the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, copy `magento-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` to your module under same directory structure.
Rename it something like `sales_order_gridx.xml`.
Replace the two occurrences of `sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid_data_source` with `sales_order_gridx.sales_order_grid_data_source`. (lines 11 and 12)

Now delete the `<action>` elements that you are wanting to remove.

Next, create the file `module_directory/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_index.xml` with the following contents:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="sales_order_gridx"/>
            <referenceBlock name="sales_order_grid" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This will replace the stock grid with our customized one.

Finally, flush the cache.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should add Magento_Sales to your module.xml sequence element.

Comment: Just wanted to add you could also create a custom admin theme and override it there as well. But a module is the faster method and probably more future proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like Aaron but need one more step to complete

Define `sales_order_gridx_data_source` in di.xml
Go to etc/adminhtml/di.xml

add code to anywhere in this file

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sales_order_gridx_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```